# How to calculate index hit rate?

Tags: mysql, indexing

i want to cacluate index hit rate

> "index hit rate" is how much many select query hit to index that i made.
> i searched in google. but it doesn't support mysql.

---

i thought that i can caculate to index hit rate using binarylog.
but i don't know how implemente it

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = 1 (Comes From server 1)
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = 2 (Comes From server 2)
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = 3 (Comes From server 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think these [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-information-schema-buffer-pool-tables.html#innodb-information-schema-buffer-pool-stats-example) it have something to do with hit rate in mysql that may you talk about

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.

Comment: thanks. but i need hit rate each index..

Comment: Switch to MariaDB; I think it has more statistics.